# How can I temporarily reconnect a fuel tank?

Tags: gas, propane

I am in the process of purchasing a home heated by propane..someone has removed the pigtail from the tank to the regulator..the tank fitting appears to be a quick disconnect type unfamiliar to me..the supply tank is 20% full which means I would like to utilize this gas to test the house appliances.

Comment: Sorry, but there's no question in this post.  What are you asking for?

Comment: Messing with gas if you don't know what you are doing is a sure fire recipe for trouble.

Answer (score 3):

If the house is unoccupied it's likely "winterized", which may include disconnecting the fuel tank. You'll likely have to contact the home owner or fuel supply company, and make an appointment for them to meet you and reconnect the tank temporarily.

**DO NOT RECONNECT THE TANK YOURSELF.** If you do not own the property, it is not yours to muck around with as you please.

Comment: You should talk with your agent about how to deal with this -- eg, lowering the price for you taking the risk of there being a gas leak or an appliance that doesn't work or some other problem.

Comment: @gregmac Typically in this situation, you'd have the seller get it hooked back up temporarily for the home inspection. They're not going to come de-winterize the house every time somebody comes to look at the property, but once a deal has been accepted it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tester is absolutely right. **Do not mess with the gas supply!** It is disconnected for a reason, either for winterization or because of a problem or leak. It is not yours to modify.

I am a certified home inspector and see homes with utilities disconnected all the time.  My advise for you is to be sure to have as a condition of sale, that a complete inspection be conducted by a licensed/certified technician or inspector with all utilities connected and appliances commissioned for testing. This is known as a "contingency" on your purchase and sale agreement. It is always the responsibility of the owner/seller to handle utilities.

**The heating plant should be inspected for proper operation and possible defects only by a licensed person.**